# how to check if the hudson is busy or not?

Tags: java, hudson, jenkins

How can check if the hudson is busy or not? Meaning i want to check if its currently executing any  build or not.

Currently am  using following thing:

```
    if(lastBuild == lastCompletedBuild){
        // hudson is free
    }
    else{
      //hudson is busy
   }
```

Is this a correct logic? What if the machine restarts/crashes after last build is updated and lastCompletedbuild is not?

Is there any API exposed which can directly be used?

Comment: You need to add more relevant tags.  I don't even know what Hudson is, if it is something to do with java, then add the java tag to your post.  People won't find your post without relevant tags.

Comment: @Caimen :Check out hudson @ http://hudson-ci.org/

Comment: I am assuming you are writing java code so I am adding the java tag to your post.  However just because you are trying to detect Hudon's status does not necessarily mean you are writing java.  Details... we need them.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine that you're running the build on?

Comment: @akshay: where is this code being executed?

Comment: I have my hudson running on machine A and  and from machine B , i want to detect if a build is running on hudson of machine A.So i want a API exposed from hundson on A , which i can call from machine B

Answer (score 7):

If you want to see what items are currently in the build queue, you can make an request to `http://your.hudson.server/hudson/queue/api/[xml|json]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to query the *Load Statistics* available at a [separate API](http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/overallLoad/api/):

```
<overallLoadStatistics>
  <busyExecutors></busyExecutors>
  <queueLength></queueLength>
  <totalExecutors></totalExecutors>
  <totalQueueLength></totalQueueLength>
</overallLoadStatistics>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Hudson's API](http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/api/).

Specifically: You can add `/api/[xml|json]` to any path in Hudson to get machine readable data of that page. For example `hudsonserver:8080/api/xml` will return the list of job and their current statuses.

However, the real question i where is this code being executed? Above, you have `lastBuild` and `lastCompletedBuild`, but where did those variables get set?

Comment: I get thosed values by calling api : http://hudson.server.com/job/myjobname/api/xml and ussing values of tag lastBuild &lastCompletedBuild

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in whether a specific job is currently building? In that case:

```
http://[hudson-host-and-path]/job/[job-name]/lastBuild/api/xml
```

has the tag `<building>` set to **true** if a build is currently happening.